# multiple checkboxes used for search in php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

This seems to be a common question as I have seen plenty of similar questions.

however, none of the answers actually pointing out how to do the selecting from mysql database and this is my issue as the moment.

basically I have a table which I store the search data in it.

it looks like this:

```
id    blond   darkHair    busty     curvy
---------------------------------------------------

1     blond               busty

2             dark hair   busty     curvy

3     blond                         curvy

4     blond                         curvy
```

and I have a form with checkboxes like so:

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
    <input name="keyword[]" type="checkbox" value="blond"  />
    <input name="keyword[]" type="checkbox" value="dark hair" />
    <input name="keyword[]" type="checkbox" value="busty"  />
    <input name="keyword[]" type="checkbox" value="curvy"  />
</form>
```

and the PHP codes like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['keyword']))
{

    $keyword = $_POST['keyword'];

 foreach ($_POST['keyword'] as $keyword) {

   $keywordarray[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conx, $keyword);


    }
   $keywords = implode (",", $keywordarray);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM girlsStaff
            WHERE (`blond` LIKE '%".$keyword."%') OR (`darkHair` LIKE '%".$keyword."%') OR (`busty` LIKE '%".$keyword."%') OR (`thin` LIKE '%".$keyword."%')" or die();


    $query = mysqli_query($conx, $sql);
```

Now, apart from converting this code to PDO or prepared statement, there is another issue which I don't understand!

it doesn't matter how many chechboxes i select... it always returns the result for last checked/selected checkbox value from mysql database....

is there something that I am missing?

i also, did `echo $keywords` at the top of my page to see whats being sent to the page and I get the value of all the selected/checked boxes being sent correctly.. so I know the issue is not there.

any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `$sql = "..." or die()` is pointless. building/assigning a string is not something that can tested for with an `or die()`. The failures that CAN occur would be fatal errors anyways. You need to `or die()` on the `mysqli_query()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require to build query dynamically.

```
<?php
$clause = " WHERE ";//Initial clause
$sql="SELECT * FROM `girlsStaff`  ";//Query stub
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['keyword'])){
        foreach($_POST['keyword'] as $c){
            if(!empty($c)){
                $sql .= $clause."`".$c."` LIKE '%{$c}%'";
                $clause = " OR ";//Change  to OR after 1st WHERE
            }   
        }
    }
echo $sql;//Remove after testing
}
?>
<form method="POST" action="#">
<form action="search.php" method="post">
 Blond:   <input name="keyword[]" type="checkbox" value="blond"  />
 Dark Hair:   <input name="keyword[]" type="checkbox" value="dark hair" />
 Busty :  <input name="keyword[]" type="checkbox" value="busty"  />
 Curvy;   <input name="keyword[]" type="checkbox" value="curvy"  />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Sample queries

2 check boxes filled

```
SELECT * FROM `girlsStaff` WHERE `dark hair` LIKE '%dark hair%' OR `curvy` LIKE '%curvy%'
```

4 filled

```
SELECT * FROM `girlsStaff` WHERE `blond` LIKE '%blond%' OR `dark hair` LIKE '%dark hair%' OR `busty` LIKE '%busty%' OR `curvy` LIKE '%curvy%'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that small change from $keyword to $keywords will solve your problem :)
Now you are looking for items like your last value from $_POST['keyword'] array.

This line:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM girlsStaff WHERE (`blond` LIKE '%".$keyword."%') OR (`darkHair` LIKE '%".$keyword."%') OR (`busty` LIKE '%".$keyword."%') OR (`thin` LIKE '%".$keyword."%')" or die();
```

You should also use IN instead of LIKE if you have list aaa, bbb, ccc...., but then you will look for elements that have exactly same string in those fields.

After change to $keywords you will have:

```
... WHERE (`blond` LIKE '%".$keywords."%')
```

will also not work due to it will mean:

```
... WHERE (`blond` LIKE '%aaa,bbb,ccc%')
```

If you want to use like (if fields in DB only contain strings from array) then I suggest to build your query in foreach loop. Example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM girlsStaff WHERE ".
foreach ($_POST['keyword'] as $keyword) {
    $sql .= "(`blond` LIKE '%".$keyword."%') OR ";
}
//and here cut last four character " OR " part that will be unusefull
```

Comment: you are using LIKE with value used with IN operator, refer to updated reply, use IN if your values match exactly those from DB, if not build your query in foreach loop

Comment: Sorry I am not sure why but I get syntax error in your Last code! also, that code doesn't look right.

Comment: Why it doesn't look right? You could print your query after build and check why you have syntax error. You could also use david code above my reply, it is deisigned same way, but in more details.

Answer (score 0):

Typos:

```
$keywords = implode (",", $keywordarray);
        ^--- with an S

WHERE (`blond` LIKE '%".$keyword."%') 
                                ^--- without an S
```

You're stuffing in your original `$_POST['keyword']` array. An array in string context is the literal word `Array`, so your query is actually executing as

```
WHERE (`blond` LIKE '%Array%')
```

Comment: I have already tried WHERE (`blond` LIKE '%".$keywords."%') with an S but i get no results at all.. not even the last checked checkbox.

Comment: paste a `var_dump($sql)` here. take a look at what generated sql really looks like.

Comment: it looks like this: `string(193) "SELECT * FROM girlsStaff
            WHERE (`blond` LIKE '%blond,dark hair%') OR (`darkHair` LIKE '%blond,dark hair%') OR (`busty` LIKE '%blond,dark hair%') OR (`thin` LIKE '%blond,dark hair%')"`

Comment: that is the issue because it is putting the keywords together like this: %blond,dark hair% and ofcourse it wont find anything like that in the database :D

Comment: you really should re-think your design. why bother testing for `darkhair LIKE blond`? It's an utter waste of cpu cycles. those fields should probably just be booleans, and you build your query dynamically `if (blond was checked) { add 'blond=true' to query }`

Comment: yeah, I think i need to redesign the database! not sure how to do it though! because each member will have one or more details like blond, dark hair, fat, thin etc etc.... so not entirely sure how else I could design the database! and i thought it would be easier to search if i put blond in blond column, and dark hair in dark hair column etc etc......